# Hide more than one json d3 group

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js

I have a json file with more than one group:

input.json:

```
{
"nodes": [
    {
        "name": "Q1",
        "group": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "Aliens",
        "group": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "Government",
        "group": 1
    },
    {
        "name":"Corporate",
        "group": 1
    },
    {
        "name":"Creatures",
        "group": 1
    },
    {
        "name":"Religion",
        "group": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "Q2",
        "group": 4
    },
    {
        "name": "Q2",
        "group": 3
    }
],
"links": [
    {
        "source": 0,
        "target": 1,
        "value": 2
    },
    {
        "source": 0,
        "target": 2,
        "value": 2
    },
    {
        "source": 0,
        "target": 3,
        "value": 2
    },{
        "source": 0,
        "target": 4,
        "value": 2
    },{
        "source": 0,
        "target": 5,
        "value": 2
    },
    {
        "source": 0,
        "target": 6,
        "value": 2
    },
    {
        "source":1,
        "target":6,
        "value": 2
    },
    {
        "source":2,
        "target":6,
        "value": 2
    }
]
}
```

Currently, I have the following code that hides the nodes of a group:

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
              .data(graph.nodes)
              .enter()
              .append("circle")
              .attr("class", "node")
              .attr("r", 20)
              .style("fill","black")
              .call(force.drag)
              .style("visibility", function(d) {
                return d.group == 1 ? "hidden" : "visible";
              })
              .on("mouseover", function(d) {
                node.style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
              })
              .on("click", function(d) {
                if(d.group == 2) {
                  node.filter(function(d) { return d.group == 1; }).style("visibility", "visible");
                  link.filter(function(d) { return d.value == 2; }).style("visibility", "visible");
                   texts.filter(function(d) { return d.group == 1; }).style("visibility", "visible");
                }
              }).on("mouseout", function(d) {
               node.style("fill","black")
            });
```

I want to hide all nodes except the one labeled as "Q2". I tried adding a second .style attribute but that doesn't work. I don't know what I should do. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Update**

```
.style("visibility", function(d) {
                return d.group == 1 ? "hidden" : "visible";return d.group == 4 ? "hidden" : "visible";
              })
```

This is what I'm looking for, except this code doesn't work. I tried making it two separate styles also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ternary operator, where before you checked for `d.group == 1` you can just check that `d.name !== 'Q2'` like so:

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
              .data(graph.nodes)
              .enter()
              .append("circle")
              .attr("class", "node")
              .attr("r", 20)
              .style("fill","black")
              .call(force.drag)
              .style("visibility", function(d) {
                return d.name !== 'Q2' ? "hidden" : "visible";
              })
              .on("mouseover", function(d) {
                node.style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
              })
              .on("click", function(d) {
                if(d.group == 2) {
                  node.filter(function(d) { return d.group == 1; }).style("visibility", "visible");
                  link.filter(function(d) { return d.value == 2; }).style("visibility", "visible");
                   texts.filter(function(d) { return d.group == 1; }).style("visibility", "visible");
                }
              }).on("mouseout", function(d) {
               node.style("fill","black")
            });
```

**-- EDIT --**

Since you asked about using multiple groups, you can allow for that as well. You can't have multiple return statements execute one after another, but you can use branching to direct the code execution to one return or the other. I wouldn't recommend a ternary operator if you want to have multiple options, since it will get long and confusing, but you can use regular if-else branching to accomplish it. For example:

```
.style("visibility", function(d) {
  if (d.group === 1 || d.group === 4) {
    return "hidden";
  } else {
    return "visible"
  }
});
```

The `||` operator is a logical OR. In pseudocode, the above just means:

*If d.group equals 1 or d.group equals 4, then return "hidden", otherwise return "visible"*

If that seems confusing, you could also draw it out more explicitly:

```
.style("visibility", function(d) {
  if (d.group === 1) {
    return "hidden";
  } 
  else if (d.group === 4) {
    return "hidden";
  }
  else {
    return "visible";
  }
});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Can I use more than one `name` ?